# simplexml_load_file does not recognize <dc:title> tags

Tags: php, html, xml, parsing

I am trying to use `simplexml_load_file()` to load an XML file and reach `<dc:title>` tags, but when I dump the `$xml` variable that loaded my xml file all the tags that starts with `<dc:` doesn't show. Is there a way of telling the parser to include them? should I use a different parser?

Here's my example file's code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" prefix="ibooks: http://vocabulary.itunes.apple.com/rdf/ibooks/vocabulary-extensions-1.0/" unique-identifier="pub-id" version="3.0" xml:lang="en">
  <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <dc:title>test</dc:title>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Code I used to check for which tags are seen:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
echo '<pre>';var_dump($xml);echo '</pre>';
```

And the result:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["prefix"]=>
    string(80) "ibooks: http://vocabulary.itunes.apple.com/rdf/ibooks/vocabulary-extensions-1.0/"
    ["unique-identifier"]=>
    string(6) "pub-id"
    ["version"]=>
    string(3) "3.0"
  }
  ["metadata"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) {
  }
}
```

metadata is in fact, empty. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `dc` is a namespace, not part of tag name. For testing purpose you can print the namespaces used in the given xml. Executing the snippet

```
$namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
var_dump($namespaces);
```

will output

```
array(3) {
  '' =>
  string(28) "http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf"
  'xml' =>
  string(36) "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
  'dc' =>
  string(32) "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
}
```

You have to register a prefix for the namespace for usage with xpath, then you can use it for selection:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('b', 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');
$a =$xml->xpath('//b:*/text()');
foreach($a as $t) {
   print($t."\n");
}
```

This will output `test` of the element you want to get.

Comment: How would I go about setting a value for one of the `<dc` elements?

Comment: Just the way I wrote, but I used namespace b for it - maybe that way is more understandable:
`$xml->registerXPathNamespace('dc', 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');
$a =$xml->xpath('//dc:*/text()');
foreach($a as $t) {
   print($t."\n");
}`

Comment: 2 years late hehe, but hanks for your time :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, I just stumbled over it - hope you solved it anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
$result = $xml->metadata->children('dc', true);
```

result of the code above is an object, now convert to array

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($result),TRUE);
```

Result of `$array`

```
array(1) {
    ["title"]=>string(4) "test"
}
```